# Google cloud GKE horizontal pod autoscaling based on Kubernetes metrics

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

[image]

I want to use the pod network received bytes count standard kubernetes metrics on HPA . Using following yaml to accomplish that but getting errors like unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: no custom metrics API (custom.metrics.k8s.io) registered

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: xxxx-hoa
  namespace: xxxxx
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: xxxx-xxx
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 6
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metricName: received_bytes_count
      targetAverageValue: 20k
```

If anybody had an experience with same kind of metrics usage that would be greatly helpful

[image]

Comment: Before you can use custom metrics, you should enable Monitoring in your Google Cloud project and install Stackdriver adapter. You can use also 3rd party software like Prometheus. Also you need to remember that `Custom metrics must be exported from your application in a specific format.` Could you specify which steps you already did?

Comment: i could view the metrics on metrics explorer added screen shot i want to create HPA for same standard metrics which is exist in metrics explorer. Please refer attached screen shot

Comment: Did you try solution from my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

To make it work, you need to deploy [Stackdriver Custom Metrics Adapter](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/autoscaling-metrics#step1). Below commands to deploy it.

```
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
    --clusterrole cluster-admin --user "$(gcloud config get-value account)"

$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/master/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter/deploy/production/adapter_new_resource_model.yaml
```

Later you need to use proper `Custom Metric`, in your case it should be `kubernetes.io|pod|network|received_bytes_count`

**Description**

In [Custom and external metrics for autoscaling workloads](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/custom-and-external-metrics) documentation you have information that you need to deploy `StackDriver Adapter` before you will be able to get custom metrics.

> Before you can use custom metrics, you must enable Monitoring in your Google Cloud project and install the Stackdriver adapter on your cluster.

Next step is to deploy your application (I've used Nginx deployment for test purpose) and create proper HPA.

In your HPA example, you have a few issues

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1 ## you can also use autoscaling/v2beta2 if you need more features, however for this scenario is ok
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: xxxx-hoa
  namespace: xxxxx # HPA have namespace specified, deployment doesnt have
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta1 # apiVersion: apps/v1beta1 is quite old. In Kubernetes 1.16+ it was changed to apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: xxxx-xxx
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 6
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metricName: received_bytes_count # this metrics should be replaced with kubernetes.io|pod|network|received_bytes_count
      targetAverageValue: 20k
```

In GKE you can choose between `autoscaling/v2beta1` and `autoscaling/v2beta2`. Your case will work with both `apiVersions`, however if you would decide to use `autoscaling/v2beta2` you will need to change manifest syntax.

Why `kubernetes.io/pod/network/received_bytes_count` ?
You are refering to Kubernetes metrics, and `/pod/network/received_bytes_count` is provided in [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes).

Why `|` instead of `/`? If you will check [Stackdriver documentation on Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/tree/master/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter#metric-names) you will find information.

> Stackdriver metrics have a form of paths separated by "/" character, but Custom Metrics API forbids using "/" character. When using Custom Metrics - Stackdriver Adapter either directly via Custom Metrics API or by specifying a custom metric in HPA, replace "/" character with "|". For example, to use custom.googleapis.com/my/custom/metric, specify custom.googleapis.com|my|custom|metric.

**Proper Configuration**

**for v2beta1**

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: xxxx-hoa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1 # In your case should be apps/v1beta1 but my deployment was created with apps/v1 apiVersion
    kind: Deployment
    name: nginx
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 6
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metricName: "kubernetes.io|pod|network|received_bytes_count"
      targetAverageValue: 20k
```

**for v2beta2**

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: xxxx-hoa
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: nginx
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 6
  metrics:
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metric:
        name: "kubernetes.io|pod|network|received_bytes_count"
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 20k
```

**Tests Outputs**

```
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason            Message
  ----            ------  ------            -------
  AbleToScale     True    SucceededRescale  the HPA controller was able to update the target scale to 2
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound  the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from pods metric kubernetes.io|pod|network|received_bytes_count
  ScalingLimited  True    TooFewReplicas    the desired replica count is more than the maximum replica count
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age                 From                       Message
  ----    ------             ----                ----                       -------
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  8m18s               horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 4; reason: pods metric kubernetes.io|pod|network|received_bytes_count above target
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  8m9s                horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 6; reason: pods metric kubernetes.io|pod|network|received_bytes_count above target
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  17s                 horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 5; reason: All metrics below target
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  9s (x2 over 8m55s)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 2; reason: All metrics below target
```

**Possible Issues with your current configuration**

In your HPA you have specified namespace but not in your target Deployment. Both, HPA and deployment should have the same namespace. With this mismatch configuration you can encounter issue below:

```
Conditions:
  Type         Status  Reason          Message
  ----         ------  ------          -------
  AbleToScale  False   FailedGetScale  the HPA controller was unable to get the target's current scale: deployments/scale.apps "nginx" not found
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                  From                       Message
  ----     ------          ----                 ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetScale  94s (x264 over 76m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  deployments/scale.apps "nginx" not found
```

In Kubernetes 1.16+, deployments are using `apiVersion: apps/v1`, you won't be able to create deployment with `apiVersion: apps/v1beta1` in Kubernets 1.16+

Comment: Perfect answer . Thanks for helping sorry for delayed reply just back from vacation

Answer (score 1):

autoscaling/v1 is an API in order to autoscale based only on CPU utilization. So, in order to autoscale based on other metrics you should use autoscaling/v2beta2. I recommend you to read this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/horizontal-pod-autoscaling#api-versions) to check API versions.